# Buffer is killed while CEDET parsing

Tags: emacs, cedet

I use latest CEDET and emacs 23.2. I found something wrong with CEDET, that is somehow my current edit buffer killed without any error message with semantic-load-enable-guady-code-helpers mode.
This symptom is strange. Does anyone have the same trouble? Or is there any way to know what's going on?

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The Emacs developers will determine whether or not there is a problem.

Comment: Do you use gnu global? I have this problem, when I have GTAGS etc. files in my project -- removing the files global creates ended the random bufffer kills.

Comment: @TomRegner clearing out the global-generated files seems to have cleared this issue up for me too. It's a shame though because gnu global was quite useful, filling some gaps left by cedet...

Answer (score 1):

Please, look to fresh version from BZR - this bug should be fixed there...